# This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT MAX(issue) AS issue_one FROM issue_list
WHERE issue NOT IN (SELECT issue FROM issue_list ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 46);
```

what is wrong with this query. it says. This version of MySQL doesn't yet support **`'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'`**

The thing I want to do here is get the maximum value of issue from issue_list table neglecting first 46 rows.

How to do that?

Comment: What's your version?

Comment: my verstion of mysql is mysql 5.6.17

Comment: _" This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'"_ then your question is _how to circumvent this_?

Comment: I just want to write the query that solve my problem.
Also answer to how to circumvent this will be appreciated.

Comment: I'd try with EXISTS instead of IN or with JOIN instead of subquery.

Comment: How about `WHERE issue NOT IN (SELECT issue FROM(SELECT issue FROM issue_list ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 46)x);`

Comment: FYI, [5.7 won't change this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/subquery-errors.html).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As [Mihai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1745672/mihai) mentions in his comment: try wrapping the sub-select in another sub-select. Looks dirty but is as close to your original query as you're going to get. Hence:

```
SELECT MAX(issue) AS issue_one 
FROM issue_list
WHERE issue NOT IN 
(SELECT issue from 
 (SELECT issue FROM issue_list ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 46) x
);
```

Comment: Thanks that worked.
Can you please suggest me what does the x do in this case?

Thanks.

Comment: @user2745337 Every subquery needs an alias,esentially a name,because it materializes the subquery,that is, treats it as a table.

Answer (score 0):

I never get Limit to work in Subquery, in either form. So what works for me...

1. Create View of Sub query with such limit or other limitation in your case it is limit keyword

   `Create View viewIssue46 as SELECT issue FROM issue_list ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 46;`
2. Write query like

   `SELECT MAX(issue) AS issue_one FROM issue_list WHERE issue NOT IN (select * from viewIssue46)`

this usually solve such issue with ease even more complex queries, plus you can use index in views and main queries.